# Int cannot be cast as String issue at runtime

Tags: java

Running my code results in the following error: `java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

This is what I have:

```
for(Map<String, Object> record: list) {
    if(((String)record.get("level")).equals("1")) {
        rootList.add(record);
    }
}
```

I have tried converting that little snippet to an Int using toString but it just gives me a compiling error. I'm new to java (and I did not write this code either) so forgive me if it's a stupid mistake.

Comment: Are the values in your map of the same class?  If so, using that class instead of "Object" would be better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Map`s holds values of type `Object`, meaning they can really hold anything as values (since everything extends `Object`); there's no guarantee that a given value will be a `String`. By your error, it would appear that one of the values in one of your maps is an `Integer`, which evidently cannot be cast to a `String`. The quick-fix is to use `toString`:

```
record.get("level").toString().equals("1")
```

But note that this will yield true for *any* object whose `toString` returns `"1"`, not just strings. If you want to only check for equality with the *string* `"1"`, then you can use `"1".equals(...)`, since `equals` can take any object as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
Object number = record.get("level");
if("1".equals(number)){

}
```

Comment: It did work, but it also gave me a nullpointerexception. Going to mess around with this, or try the other one to get it working.

Comment: Joda condition + null check. That's weird.

Comment: @jigarJoshi yeah I figured it was `number` so I changed it and it did compile & run. Also gave me an nullpointerexception even though it still ran. Messing around with it now.

Comment: Ignore my first comment, you can just do `"1".equals(record.get("level"))` - no need for the null check.

Comment: nullpointerexception is coming from elsewhere. This + other's worked. Thanks a ton folks.

Answer (score 0):

try one of this alternatives:

rootList.add(record + "");

or

rootList.add(new String(record));

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the `Map` values are `Integer`s, then `toString()` should work for converting them to strings:

```
for(Map<String, Object> record: list) {
    if(record.get("level").toString().equals("1")) {
        rootList.add(record);
    }
}
```

Comment: The cast is unnecessary in your version.